# C++ Char Loop Check

Tags: c++, loops, char

I'm still very much a beginner at programming and I'm trying to figure out why this loop won't work. The user is asked to input a char, and I figured I'd do a check to see if the char is one of three correct letters. If it isn't, they can retry until it's correct. That's the idea, at least.

```
char readOp()
{
    char op;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please choose desired operation: (a: add, m: multiply, s: squared)" << endl;
        cin.ignore(); //I was getting double cout, this removed one of them.
        op = cin.get();
    } while (op != 'a' && op != 'm' && op != 's');

    cout << "Got " << op << endl;
    return op;
}
```

Edited to reflect changes: I've solved a few things but I'm still not able to get my loop to work. Right now the problem is that the loop won't terminate upon supplying the correct chars.

If it makes any difference, the whole segment is a char function.

What am I missing? Am I just tired because it's 04:04?

Comment: where does cout statement end?

Comment: @JayKumarR Sorry, I forgot to add it in my example! :)

Comment: Works fine after minor changes. See it at http://ideone.com/nuRinO.

Comment: @Pang What do you mean by ending double quote?

Comment: @Pang I see what you mean now, found it and fixed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow solved my own code.

I swapped `op = cin.get();` back to the original `cin >> op;` and removed `cin.ignore();` and now it works like magic. I don't know why, but I'll take it. :P Thanks for the other help!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be any real problem with your code, but you may see the infinite loop because you somehow have gotten end-of-file and you are not testing for that.   Just add a reasonable handling of EOF, for example like this;

```
char readOp() {
  char op;
  cout << "Please enter ....blah blah" << endl;
  do {
    if (cin.eof()) return 'x';  // <-- add some EOF handling
    cin >> op;
  } while (op != 'a' && op != 'm' && op != 's');
  cout << "exit";
  return op;
}
```

**Edit:**
You should also look at the code that is calling `readOp` -- I bet (guess) that there is a outer-loop there which is not testing the return value correctly and therefore is calling `readOp` again.

Comment: Hmm, I probably should have mentioned it's only an excerpt of my code, it continues after the loop is finished. Unless I'm mistaking what end-of-file is.

Comment: The input your are reading from `cin` will have end of file condition at some point -- if a terminal that is when you press ctl-d -- if in a pipe or socket that is when the other side closes -- and with a file, it is when the file is ended

Comment: I tried adding the EOF handling, but it gave me the same results as before. Still, thanks! :)

Comment: You may need to add more context, including the data you are passing into the program -- I have voted to close the question, since we cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: Well, I'm not passing any values into the function, if that's what you mean. All it does is have the user decide which operation they want, and it returns that char.

Comment: you need to update the problem description to something where other people can reproduce your problem

Answer (score -1):

I would use std::string to receive the input of the user with `std::cin`

```
string op;
do
{
    cout << "Please enter desired operation: (a: add, m: multiply, s: squared)";
    cin >> op;
} while (op != "a" && op != "m" && op != "s");
```

Comment: That is more a code review issue, than fixing his problem -- unless you think using std::string actually fixing the problem he is asking about

Comment: The problem is fixed by the code. The user can definitely input a char (or other strings), and the loop does not run indefinitely as it did before.